# Reference for a proof of Ceitin's theorem (Borel computable = Markov computable)?

Tags: reference-request, computable-analysis

Ceitin's theorem says that if a function $\mathbb R_c \to \mathbb R_c$ is Markov computable, then it is Borel computable (or TTE-computable). I find this theorem on Klaus Weihrauch's *Computable Analysis - An Introduction*. This seems a really famous and beautiful results, but I cannot find a proof. All references are extremely hard to find by all means. It is such a pity.

Does anyone know where can one find the proof of this amazing result is?

Comment: In Weihrauch's book, there are references to proofs; following them, one gets to an easily accessible proof here: [Theorem 42 in Spreen, 2001, TCS 262](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397500003194).

Comment: Tseytin's original proof is easily accessible [here (in Russian)](https://www.mathnet.ru/links/336fe70a682151bed19e48d7b2142c57/tm1758.pdf).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Thank you!